# Creating executable of an an application in python. After executing "python setup.py py2exe" command getting and error [Error2]

Tags: python-2.7

from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob

import py2exe

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT*.*'))]

setup(console=['hello.py'])

Comment: Below is the error mentioned.
creating python loader for extension '_socket' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd -> _socket.pyd)
*** finding dlls needed ***
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numpy-atlas.dll'

Comment: i just copy pasted the "numpy-atlas.dll" file into the folder where "_socket.pyd" is present and now it is giving me an error that following packages are missing.
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Appearance', 'Carbon.Files', 'ElementC14N', 'Image', 'Numeric', '__svn_version__',
_thread', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', '_thread', 'backports.ssl_match_hostname', 'builtins',
code_generators.genapi', 'code_generators.numpy_api', 'compat.long', 'configparser', 'copyreg', 'core.
'core.min', 'core.round', 'dummy.Process', 'elementtree.ElementTree', 'fcompiler.FCompiler',